# Como hacer que se repita una sentencia hasta que sea correcta

Tags: java, netbeans

quisiera saber como puedo hacer que se repita el codigo hasta que sea correcto, en este caso mayor a 400hrs

```
/**
 * Metodo para obtener las horas de vuelo del piloto, con validacion de mayor a 400.
 */
public int HorasVuelo(){
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    int fakeHoraVuelo;
    System.out.println("Ingrese las horas de vuelo del piloto");
    fakeHoraVuelo = sc.nextInt();
    if(fakeHoraVuelo < 400){
        System.out.println("Lo sentimos, se necesita un Piloto con mas experiencia");
    }
    else{
        System.out.println("Esplendido!");
        HorasDeVuelo = fakeHoraVuelo;
    }
return HorasDeVuelo;   
}
```

osea, si ingresa por ejemplo 300, que le diga el mensaje y vuelva al inicio a pedir las horas de vuelo otra vez

Comment: usa un while...

Comment: lo he pensado y no me lo he currado en verdad, no se si en java permite usar un while true, en python lo hacia de esa manera

Comment: No debes usar while True, esa es una mala practica, crea un flag  y repite hasta que la sentencia cambie: `bool esCorrecta = false; while(!esCorrecta){ tu_codigo if(fakeHoraVuelo > 400) esCorrecta=true;}`

Comment: Prueba lo siguiente: `public int HorasVuelo(){
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    int fakeHoraVuelo;
    do{
        System.out.println("Ingrese las horas de vuelo del piloto");
        fakeHoraVuelo = sc.nextInt();
        if(fakeHoraVuelo < 400){
            System.out.println("Lo sentimos, se necesita un Piloto con mas experiencia");
        }
        else{
            System.out.println("Esplendido!");
            HorasDeVuelo = fakeHoraVuelo;  
        }
    }
    while(fakeHoraVuelo<400)
    return HorasDeVuelo;       
}
`

Comment: vale, creo que lo he pillado, lo puse en una respuesta por si quieres echarle un ojo y me corrijas algun error

Answer (score 1):

Aqui tienes una respuesta funcional a partir de tu codigo:

```
public int HorasVuelo(){
    int fakeHoraVuelo = 0;
    int horasDeVuelo = 0;
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

    while(fakeHoraVuelo < 400){
        System.out.println("Ingrese las horas de vuelo del piloto");
        fakeHoraVuelo = sc.nextInt();



        if(fakeHoraVuelo < 400){
            System.out.println("Lo sentimos, se necesita un Piloto con mas experiencia");
        }
        else{
            System.out.println("Esplendido!");
            horasDeVuelo = fakeHoraVuelo;
        }

    }

return horasDeVuelo;   
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Has probado con un ciclo `do-while`?.

Ejemplo funcional a partir de tu código:

```
do{
    System.out.println("Ingrese las horas de vuelo del piloto");
    fakeHoraVuelo = sc.nextInt();

    if(fakeHoraVuelo < 400) // Validar número y dar feedback
        System.out.println("Lo sentimos, se necesita un Piloto con mas experiencia");

    else {
        System.out.println("Esplendido!");
        HorasDeVuelo = fakeHoraVuelo;
       }
} while (fakeHoraVuelo < 400); // Condición

return HorasDeVuelo;
```